# With activerecord how can I stop memory thrashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I reuse an active record object, while creating a set of new objects.

Take the following code for example:

```
loop do
  foo = Foo.new
  foo.bar = 'value'
  foo.save!
end
```

This causes ruby to allocate a new object every time `Foo.new` is called. Which is slow, and stabs the GC right in the heart.

So is there a way where I can re use the `foo` object like this (in this case .reset is incorrectly used)

```
foo = Foo.new
loop do
  foo.reset
  foo.bar = 'value'
  foo.save!
end
```

So this way, the object is duplicated by inserting it multiple times into the database, rather than creating new objects in memory.

A more complete use case of this is pulling data in off a message queue.

```
queue.subscribe do |data|
  foo = Foo.new
  foo.data = data
  foo.save!
end
```

Comment: Short answer: Not without executing raw SQL, and ignoring AR objects altogether.

Comment: ActiveRecord objects are by design one-per-row. Going against this goes against the AR pattern and "stuff blows up". Even if the attributes are reset to `nil`'s, ActiveRecord will still think it's not a new object after it was saved: it will literally attempt to save it with `NULL` as primary key and fail. Just tested it out.

Comment: @D-side you should make that an answer.

Comment: I think you both might be correct. I guess it is breaking the ORM model a bit. So the options is to thrash memory, or skip AR and use straight SQL.

Comment: @JesseWhitham done. I doubt it's very helpful though.

Comment: @D-side on the contrary, while it may not give the OP exactly what they want, it's an excellent explanation. It needs more up votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd hate to say **no**, but **there's no way to do that and keep following the [Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)**, which is a principle under the hood of Rails' ActiveRecord. As the Wikipedia article states:

> an object instance is tied to a single row in the table

From that you can tell, that you cannot map a **single** object to **multiple** distinct rows.

Rails' ActiveRecord objects come in two different forms that look alike but work differently inside:

- **Not persisted objects** (results of `new`, `association.build` and maybe some others)
  They don't have `id`s yet, they're not yet valid "Active Records", that implies that on save a new row in the database is created and the object is considered persisted from that moment.
- **Persisted objects** (received from the database in any way)
  An object considered a valid row in the database without most implications. Any operation with that object should be reasonable in context of a RDBMS.

That said, to do that, you'd have to dive into the depths of AR implementation, because to "unpersist" an AR object (if you follow the pattern) you have to remove it from the database. No exceptions in current AR's implementation.

Here's a little experiment. Once we have an unpersisted object, we can examine it and find out it has an `id` equal to `nil`. Now let's get a persisted object and do this:

```
# assume we did `t = Thing.first` before
t.id = nil
t.save!
```

Create a new object? No! Update existing one!

```
UPDATE `things` SET `id` = NULL WHERE `things`.`id` = 1
```

Of course, DB rejects this query because it's not reasonable in terms of RDBMS to set primary key of any record to `NULL`:

```
Column 'id' cannot be null
```

Why? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906811/null-permitted-in-primary-key-why-and-in-which-dbms). Briefly, that's because `NULL != NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = [Foo.new, bar: []]
// and foo[0] is the Foo.new object 
loop do
  foo.bar.pop()
  foo.bar.push('value')
end
```

I think your code was a bit overcensored and you should've given us more info, but this is how I would store a Foo object and a changing `foo.bar` value, and never creating new arrays or causing memory leaks