# Can a Primary key column accept the Null value? I'm using sqlite studio for learning and it accepts

Tags: sqlite

Can a Primary key column accept the Null value? I'm using SQLiteStudio for learning and it accepts.

It is accepting multiple null values in the table of 5 columns, where the following query is executed:

```
Insert into EmployeeDB (Name, Age)
Values ('Raja3', '85');
```

Here 2 columns are given a value, so all other columns are updated as Null in which one column is defined as PRIMARY Key and one as UNIQUE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906811/null-permitted-in-primary-key-why-and-in-which-dbms

Comment: In my table the column I set PK is a String value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Unless the Column is an Integer Primary Key, SQLite (Only SQLite) allows Primary Key to Possess a Null Value.  NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs. This can be resolved by adding NOT NULL constraint to the Column Field.

Comment: This is working when I configure the column to 'Not null', but what is the purpose of Primary key? why the key feature of PK is not working? Pls help.

Comment: There are some inconsistencies with SQLite. By the times this issue was discovered, SQLite was in a wide use and fixing the problem could have created havoc in the existing systems. It might get fixed in the Future.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Primary key can't accept NULL values. Unique key can accept only ONE NULL values.

Can i know which column is defined as primary key and which one is defined as Unique key. If possible show me the Structure of the table

Answer (score -2):

Primary key column does not accept null values. It is not possible. Can you show properties of all columns in this table please?