# "Warn on null primary keys" table design option in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, ssms

I SSMS (2008R2) menu Tools --> Options --> Designers --> Table and Database Designers --> "Warn on null primary keys" 
I played checking and unchecking this checkbox but could not detect the differences.
What is it for?

My related questions, probably:

- [NULL permitted in Primary Key - why and in which DBMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906811/null-permitted-in-primary-key-why-and-in-which-dbms)
- [Why to use “not null primary key” in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905703/why-to-use-not-null-primary-key-in-tsql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it would seem that when this is checked, if any of the columns are nullable, it will produce a warning stating

> Primary Key cannot be created on
>   Column 'X' because it allows null
>   values.
>
> Clear the Allow Nulls check box for
>   each column in the primary key.

Whereas if this is not check, and you make columns the primary key, they will automatically be changed to non nullable.