# Why specify primary key not null when creating a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

A piece of sql in sql server

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

Primary key is not null by nature, why we still specify not null here? Do I miss anything?

Comment: check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905703/why-to-use-not-null-primary-key-in-tsql

Answer (score 5):

Yes, "primary key" is "not null", by definition.

Q: Do you object to typing in eight extra characters?

Q: Have you tried *omitting* "not null"?  What happens?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use it, it's redundant...

Answer (score 1):

Because `Primary key` will not contain `NULL` value. This key is the Identifier of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is copy-paste from auto-generated script, and Not Null is coming from column settings, and primary key from constraint definition?