# Is it pointless marking primary key as not null in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench and every time I add a primary key it automatically ticks the "Not Null" checkbox.

Would I be correct is un-ticking this? 
Shouldn't marking it as the primary key automatically apply the not null constraint?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why to use "not null primary key" in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905703/why-to-use-not-null-primary-key-in-tsql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question's solution is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905806 I would leave it ticked if I were you.